# How to use mongoID's

Tags: php, mongodb

Hi I'm making a web app using mongoDB for the persistence later, I was wondering how you could use the mongo ID automatically generated to point to a common row in a collection. For example we have a users collection (with an '_id' field) and another collection to store the user's API key information. How would it be possible to link these two so that the '_id' in the API key collection corresponds to the user collection so that they point to the right user. This is being done in PHP 5.

Thanks in advance,
RayQuang

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design#SchemaDesign-Embedvs.Reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite the default id with your own id.
So when you do an insert, you can set "_id" in your object, equivalent to the mongoid
present in your API key collection.

example code :

```
<?php

$objectFromAPICollection =  find_object_from_API_collection;

$userid = $objectFromApiCollection["_id"] ;

$theObjId = new MongoId($userid);

$connection = new Mongo();

$objectToInsert = array( "_id" => $theObjId , "data" => $someData );

// this will return our matching entry.
$connection->selectDB('someDb')->selectCollection('users')->insert($objectToInsert);
```

?>